# Keras, K.repeat_elements leads to AttributeError:'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I have a layer with dimension (None,1,B), and I would like to clone its rows such that I get something like (None,A,B). My idea is using the following command:

```
layer1 = K.repeat_elements(layer, A, axis=1)
```

As a result I get the following error:

> AttributeError:'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'

I believe the reason is that repeat_elements creates some kind of layer which is not a Keras layer. Any alternatives or ideas on how to check if this is a Keras layer or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use backend functions directly into tensors produced by Keras layers, you need to wrap them into a `Lambda` layer with a lambda function or similar:

```
layer1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.repeat_elements(x, A, axis=1))(layer)
```